# Retrieve owl-carousel item index when clicking on div inside this carousel item

Tags: javascript, jquery, owl-carousel

I have an owl carousel with dynamically added items and each of them contains a remove button.

When I click on this button, I want to get the itemindex of the parent carousel item to call the remove event of my carousel.

How can I retrieve this index ?

I really need item index of the parent item of my button because many carousel item are shown at once and I don't want the 'current item index'

What I tried :

```
//retrieve parent item of clicked button
var owlitem = $(this).parents('.owl-item');

var index = $('.owl-carousel').data('owl.carousel')._items.indexOf(owlitem);
```

But it returns -1

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use changed event to track the current index:

```
// Listen to owl events:
owl.on('changed.owl.carousel', function(event) {
    var currentItem = event.item.index;
    window.location.hash = currentItem + 1;
})
```

Comment: Thank you but as I said, I don't want the current index because many items are shown at once and the user can close any of them, not only the current item